# How to find occurances of a string in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, count, find-occurrences

I am trying to count the total number of (First column closed) *Closed* records. But I Get the result like 1.00 and 0.00 .

Desired results:

[image: count]

Code:

```
Local NumberVar str := 0; 
Local NumberVar strLen := count({@Status}); 
Local NumberVar i; 

For i := 1 To strLen Do ( 
  If instr(i, {@Status}, "Closed") <> 0 Then 
    str := str + 1; 
); 

If(str > 0 ) Then str
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two obvious options:

1) Running total with a evaluation expression: `instr({@Status}, "Closed") <> 0` set to count
2) Create a new formula `if instr({@Status}, "Closed") <> 0 then 1 else 0` then you can summarize that (either in a formula or using a "summary")

Comment: Thank you For your answer.... First i apply (if instr({@Status}, "Closed") <> 0 then 1 else 0) this code after that using Sum I get the total count

Answer (score 1):

Your formula should be:

```
// formula's result might not always be 'Closed'
IIf( InStr({@Status}, "Closed") > 0, 1, 0 )
```

or

```
// formula's result is clean
IIf( {@Status}="Closed", 1, 0 )
```

** edit **

Insert a summary field that references this formula.  By the way, this formula doesn't need to be added to the canvas to function correctly.